# inputting list elements to a mutate loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, levels

I have a very messy dataset that need to pre-process. 
I would like to change all variables and add the levels information manually so I am trying to make a loop which uses mutate on it.

I managed to create a list which has the row numbers of the variables I need to change in a dataframe (eg.varstochange). I also generated two list, the first one has the levels that this variables have (see levelnumbers), and the second one has the labels to use (see levelnames).

I am very new to loops and using mutates is becoming difficult with the magittr way of writing

```
 tempdat<- data.frame(location=c("1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","1"),job=c(1,0 ,1,0,1,0,1,0,1),age=c(12,12,13,14,15,13,1,14,14))

varstochange<-c(1,2)

levelnames<-list()
levelnames[[1]]=c("Europe","Africa","Asia")
levelnames[[2]]=c("yes","no")

levelnumbers<-list()
levelnumbers[[1]]=c("1","2","3")
levelnumbers[[2]]=c("0","1")
```

I was trying to write something like this, but really not sure where to start and how to tell the function to pick elements from three independent lists and input it into the mutate loop....

This is where I got stuck.

```
  for (i in 1:length(varstochange)){
  input<-tempdat%>%
 mutate(varstochange[i]=factor(tempdat[i],levels=c(unlist(levelnumbers[i])),l abels=c(unlist(levels_names[i])),order=TRUE))
   }
```

At the end I would like to have a dataset that only changes the format of the variables to the ones on the "varstochange", and that has a structure with the levels defined in the other two lists.

I would appreciate any help in making this work
thanks!

Comment: How many columns do you need to recode? Do you have just many levels for a few columns, or also many columns?

Comment: If there are many columns, can you assume that `tempdat` and the `level` lists are in the correct, corresponding order?

Answer (score 1):

In general you shouldn't and don't need to loop with `dplyr` like that. Try just using `recode` like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
tempdat <- tibble(
  location = c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "1"),
  job = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
  age = c(12, 12, 13, 14, 15, 13, 1, 14, 14)
)
tempdat %>%
  mutate(
    location = recode(location, "1" = "Europe", "2" = "Africa", "3" = "Asia"),
    job = recode(job, "1" = "yes", "0" = "no")
  )
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   location job     age
#>   <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 Europe   yes      12
#> 2 Africa   no       12
#> 3 Asia     yes      13
#> 4 Europe   no       14
#> 5 Africa   yes      15
#> 6 Asia     no       13
#> 7 Europe   yes       1
#> 8 Africa   no       14
#> 9 Europe   yes      14
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks for your help Calum, though, the reason why I don't want use a similar code to the one you suggested above is because I have a list of 722 levels and labels!!!, and doing it by hand as you suggested above will take ages and could lead to many mistakes. Do you have any suggestion to input the list of levels and labels directly from the lists into the data frame?

Comment: Ah it was not clear that you had predetermined lists. I thought that if you are typing the levels into lists anyway just put them as arguments to the function. I'll submit another answer